# What is the default representation of date in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using a visualization tool called Dangle.js built on D3.js, and I was wondering what was the default representation for the date using d3.time.scale(). The code for the representation of an area graph includes this line to represent the x-axis scale

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);
```

Right now the data to be included in the graph is :

```
    $scope.graph = {
    entries: [
      {time: "20120320", count: 100},
      {time: "20120321", count: 20},
      {time: "20120322", count: 43},
      {time: "20120323", count: 83}
    ]
};
```

However, the 'time''s of the data are in the wrong format, so it is not being represented at dates on the x-axis as they should be. What format should the date be for the data? An example would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The default representation of d3's time scale is the [JavaScript Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Best practice is to convert the date strings in your data to Date objects on load.  This can be done, for instance, using D3's built in [date/time formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting):

```
var dateFormatIn = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d");

entries.forEach(function(entry) {
  entry.time = dateFormatIn.parse(entry.time);
});
x.domain( d3.extent(entries, function(d) { return d.time; }) );
```

Simple jsfiddle [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/M6DZg/).

Answer (score 1):

The d3 `time.format` only string-formats Date objects and won't coerce other values. It has a [parse method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse) to convert a string into a Date object, in a format you can specify.

`d3.time.scale` domains work with Date objects, but if you pass it Numbers, the `domain()` method would coerce those values into dates (i.e. interpret them as milliseconds since 1970) .